# MDX SSAS calculating the average of a measure taking distinct users into account

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to add a calculation in `BIDS 2008R2`: the average `DaysSinceLastOrder` taking into account the unique users (and each of their average DaysSinceLastOrder times)

for example, if my orders table has these rows:

```
customerID  daysSinceLastOrder
1           null
1           1
1           3
2           6
3           null
```

then I want `((1 + 3)/2 + 6) / 2 = 4` avg days since last order

In words:
for each user, figure out the average of that user's `daysSinceLastOrder`
then take the average of those values
but ignore orders with a null `daysSinceLastOrder` value

Obviously this basic calculation doesn't work since it ignores the uniqueness of customers in the numerator:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Avg Days Since Last Order]
    AS [Measures].[daysSinceLastOrder] / [Measures].[#UniqueCustomers]
```

in SQL it would be:

```
select AVG(t.avgDaysSinceLastOrder) as avgDaysSinceLastOrder
from (
  select customerID, AVG(daysSinceLastOrder) as avgDaysSinceLastOrder
   from orders  
   group by customerID  
) t
```

So how can I make that work in `MDX`?

Update:
Effectively I want something like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Avg Days Since Last Order]
    AS sum(avg_daysSinceLastOrder_per_customer) / [Measures].[#Unique Customers]
```

I tried the following which doesn't work, it just averages everything, not on a per-customer basis:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Avg Days Since Last Order]
    AS sum([Customers].[User Id],
          sum([Customers].[User Id], [Measures].[Days Since Last Order]))
       / [Measures].[#Unique Customers]
```

**Notes**:

- `daysSinceLastOrder` measure is pre-calculated during `ETL` (with `SUM` as the aggregation type in the cube)
- #UniqueCustomers obivously is a measure in the cube (and would have 3 in this case) which isn't quite what I want to use above
- a null `daysSinceLastOrder` value means it's that customer's first order

Comment: How is it possible for a customer to have more than one "days since last order"?  That type of measure is typically implemented as a calculation so that it is always up to date...

Comment: if the cube cell is not by single day. e.g. if I'm looking at all orders for a month, or all orders for a given store, then one customer could have purchased on different days, and each of those purchases would have a different (pre-calculated) DaysSinceLastOrder. So yes, for each order, the DaysSinceLastOrder is calculated during ETL and is correct. The problem is performing a good average calculation

Comment: actually it can happen even on one day, if a customer places multiple orders. so one reason to do the more complicated average is to keep one user from distorting it.  e.g. if 2 customers placed orders on Mar 1, and one of them placed 9 orders, each with a DaysSinceLastOrder of 2, and the other customer placed 1 order with a DaysSinceLastOrder of 6, doing a simple average would give 2.4 ((9*2 + 6)/10), whereas the more complicated/correct one would give 4 ((2+6)/2)

Comment: ahhhh, ok i think I gotcha now...you're trying to calculate the average time between events, in this case orders across customer base.

Comment: yes, i if it like banton says you should rename your measure since it make no sense, i would suggest avgTimeBetweenOrders or something like that.

Comment: ok, so think of it as avgTimeBetweenOrdersPerCustomer, averaged up. Is it possible?